# exectue list of python in database

Tags: python, mysql

My code in python for finding all primes numbers to any given limit, using sieve of eratosthenes

```
"""my_code"""
import time
start = time.time()
L= list(range(2,100000))
for i in L[:]:
    for j in L:
        k=j%i
        #print(j)
        if k==0 and i!=j:
            L.remove(j)

print (L)
print ("sum is:",sum(L))
print("len is", len(L))
end = time.time()
print("time is",end-start)
"""my_code"""
```

The code is correct but I have a problem, when I want to find all prime numbers from 2 to 2 million, the code takes a long time. I've had to wait a day without getting the result.

My friend gave me an idea, it's to try to execute the list in database using mysql. I don't know how, so if anyone has a solution of the problem or idea please help.

Comment: What does MySQL have to do with your actual question?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Where does the algorithm get stuck?

Comment: *try to execute the list in database using mysql*. Did you execute? What does executing the list means here? There are couple of places which can be improved in your code which can make your code little faster. But could not really understand how database comes to the rescue here

Comment: the problem is take long time without get result when i want to find prime number from 1 to 2 million, my friend think if i try to use database to accelerate the execution. he guess the RAM cant handle the code,

Comment: mad, ok can u show how i can make my code littl faster, cuz that's the point

Answer (score 0):

Approximately 60% improvement in execution times with just a couple of changes. As a thumb rule do use remove the elements while iterating the same list.

```
import time
start = time.time()
out=[]
L= range(2,100000) # Do not convert it into list
for i in L:
    for j in range(2,int(i/2)+1): # Do not execute till the last element of L. Seriously no point in doing so
         if i%j==0:
            break # break as soon as you found out that the number is not prime.
         if j==i-1:
            out.append(i)

end = time.time()
print("time is",end-start)
```

You code took around 140 secs while mine took 50 secs approx to execute and find first one million prime number.